# Doctrine 2 - PHP Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine\\ORM\\EntityRepository' not found

Tags: doctrine-orm, repository

It was not after searching here for a solution that I decided to ask this question. Some other fellow "askers" have done it here and although I've tried some of the possible solutions provided, I keep getting the same error.

PHP doesn't seem to be able to find the EntityRepository class although I've followed Doctrine's tutorial word by word.

Here's my setup:

repositories/UserRepository.php

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class UsersRepository extends Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository {

    public function getAllUsers(){
        $dql = 'SELECT u.id, u.name FROM Users u';
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql);
        return $query->getResult();

    }     

}
```

entities/Users.php

```
// This tells Doctrin which table to use from the schema
/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="UsersRepository")
 * @Table(name="users")
 **/    

class Users {

    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue
     **/        
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string")
     **/        
    protected $name;    

    public function __construct() {

    }

    public function setUserName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getUserName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }


}
```

and in the bootstrap file - /bootstrap.php - I added

```
// including all repositories
require_once 'repositories/UsersRepository.php';
```

when I run /getUsers.php

```
require_once 'bootstrap.php';

echo '<p>fetching all users</p>';

$allUsers = $b->entityManager->getRepository('Users')->getAllUsers();
```

that's when I get the error in my apache error log. If anyone ever ran into the same situation, please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

open your bootstrap.php File and switch the require_once code **below** the require_once of bootstrap_doctrine.php:

```
if (!class_exists("Doctrine\Common\Version", false))
{
    require_once ("bootstrap_doctrine.php");
}

require_once "repositories/UsersRepository.php";
```